# how to design a multiplier digital circuit using 4bit adders with output in BCD?

Tags: digital-logic

I want to design a circuit that multiplies a number by 6 an input binary number using only 4bit full adders. I designed the combinational logic but couldn't do it with 4bit adders as i were asked in my exam. any help?

Comment: What is the input width?  You might want to start by figuring out which bits in the output depend on which bits in the input.

Comment: the input is only one digit (4 bits)

Comment: I have considered the 6(0110) as the multiplier and the input(wxyz) as the multiplicand and made the mathematical operation with my hand and I have found that we need to add two numbers (wxy+wxyz) if i implement that with BCD adder , will I get the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Given you only need to multiply by 6, rather than a variable, split up the calculations into simple operations.

6 in binary is `110` which means \$1\times4 + 1\times2 + 0\times1 = 4 + 2\$. So how could you calculate \$6\times a\$ simply?

> Hint: How do you multiply a number by 2 using only addition?

So how do you calculation \$6\times a\$ using only adders?

Comment: Hint: In binary you don't even need an adder to multiply by 2.

Comment: Do you mean that multiplication is just a repetitive addition?

Comment: The problem is how to get the answer in BCD?